# CCParticleSystemQuad isRunning/particleCount behaviour

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

I have some questions regarding the **isRunning** and **particleCount** properties of CCParticleSystemQuad.

I'm currently managing reuse of particle systems, thus I need a boolean check for if the system is currently running.

The two properties that I thought of trying are the ones I have a problem with

My code snips

```
    // getParticleSystemForFile
    if( !psq.isRunning ) { // tried replacing this with psq.particleCount
        [psq resetSystem];
        return psq;
    }
```

and

```
    //
    CCParticleSystemQuad *effect = [[GameObjSingleton get] getParticleSystemForFile:@"healEffect.plist"];
    if ( effect.parent ) {
        [effect.parent removeChild:effect cleanup:NO];
    }
```

The current behaviour is something like this:

**isRunning** - always returning 1

**particleCount** - always returning 0

So when I use particleCount, no new effects are created. When I use isRunning, new particle systems are always created

Comment: if the system doesn't have a fixed duration like ccparticleexplosion it will always remain running

Comment: It does have a finite positive duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check the `active` property.

`isRunning` is a property of CCNode which tells you whether the node is paused or not in the scene graph.